# In iOS what is the correct or most efficient way to rotate through multiple map overlays via a button action?

Tags: ios, ios7, mkmapview, mkoverlay

What I am trying to do is load an initial map overlay (which I have successfully done), but allow the user to scroll/rotate through other map overlays by tapping on a button to go back and forth through the overlays. What I want to know is what is the correct or most efficient way of removing a map overlay and displaying a new overlay.

Current implementation method:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MapViewOverlay *mapOverlay = (MapViewOverlay *)overlay;
    MapViewOverlayView *mapOverlayView = [[MapViewOverlayView alloc] initWithOverlay:mapOverlay];

    return mapOverlayView;
}
```

Comment: I realize this method is now deprecated for iOS 7.

Comment: Have you tried simply doing removeOverlay/removeOverlays with the existing overlay(s) and then addOverlay with the new one?

Comment: @Anna No, but I want to keep the rendered overlay cache, but remove it and show another one. I will have the possibility of going back to the previous overlay, and I don't want to reload it.

Comment: @Anna If you post an answer, I will accept it for now as I have not found any other solutions.